# Do I Have to Put @Secured Annotations on Interface or on Class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Is it correct to put `@Secured` annotations on interface methods or on methods within classes implementing the interface? Are there any recommendations for this?

When I dig into the class defining the `@Secured` annotation, I can see that it has the `@Inherited` annotation set:

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface Secured {
    /**
     * Returns the list of security configuration attributes (e.g. ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN).
     *
     * @return String[] The secure method attributes
     */
    public String[]value();
}
```

Having read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10596870/3077218), I guess I can set the `@Secured` annotation on the interface to consistently enforce authorization over all implementations of the interface.

Comment: As written [here](http://kim.saabye-pedersen.org/2013/05/spring-annotation-on-interface-or-class.html), you can annotate interfaces but it only works "if you are using interface-based proxies." In general, Java annotations are not inherited from interfaces.

Comment: @Andre, If the answer is helpful, then you should accept my answer for fellow user of Stackoverflow.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna done. thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your provided link said, `@Transactional` is also `@Inherited`. Lets break down each part of them.

As per spring's [developers recommended](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html) that use `@Transactional` annotation with concrete class.
You can use `@Transactional` annotation in interface or a method inside the interface. You can think this will work as you expected if you used *`interface-based-proxies`*. Annotation that is not inherited refers that if you are using *`class-based-proxies`* then probably transaction attribute are not applied to that interface. So the ultimate object can not covered or wrapped by transactional attribute.

If so, `@Secured` annotation is `@Inherited` then this can be used both in interface and its implementation class.
From spring [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/annotation/Secured.html):

> The Secured annotation is used to define a list of security configuration attributes for business methods.

For example:

```
 @Secured({ "ROLE_USER" })
 public void create(Contact contact);

 @Secured({ "ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN" })
 public void update(Contact contact);

 @Secured({ "ROLE_ADMIN" })
 public void delete(Contact contact);
```

So In the bottom line, you may have multiple implementations for an interface. So, keeping your `@Secured` annotation in interface makes sense.